# Why we can't see suggested edits rendered in latex before approving?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, mathjax, review, suggested-edits

I've noticed that when viewing suggested edits there is an option to show rendered output but it doesn't actually show what the edit will look like after latex has been compiled.  I realize there is value to seeing the exact changes in a post before compiling latex but many times it would be far easier to see if an edit is helpful if we could see what both posts look like after fully compiling latex.  Why isn't this possible?

Comment: You can see what the rendered post looks like, if you click on "improve" (and then you can return back to review). This was suggested here (and maybe in some other posts): http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2809/reviewing-suggested-edits

Comment: Click "improve" then return, but careful not to click improve on a review audit where the edit is clearly vandalism by the Community bot.

Comment: These suggestions are helpful but the process is still a lot more cumbersome than it needs to be.  I don't know exactly how this kind of thing would be changed but is it not a realistic request?  It seems like it wouldn't be that hard to fix and really has no downside.  There would just be an additional option to view the compiled latex.

Comment: Sometimes I alter the LaTeX by a tiny amount, and that shows the latex. Always remember to replace the thing you removed though